# Match up instances 2 lists in pymongo

Tags: mongodb

I am using pipelines in pymongo to query a json file.

I have one list, "sixcities" containing the 6 'cities' with the 'highest count' of book shops i.e. the least book shops.  (contains 6 pymongo instances)

```
    {'_id': 'city1', 'count': 84}
    {'_id': 'city2', 'count': 65}
    {'_id': 'city3', 'count': 61}
    {'_id': 'city4', 'count': 59}
    {'_id': 'city5', 'count': 84}
    {'_id': 'city6', 'count': 64}
```

I have a second list, "travelcities" with the counts of Travel Book shops in each of the 'cities' ( 20+) in the json file.  (contains 20+pymongo instances)
                {'_id': 'city1', 'count': 42}...etc

Please note:This list holds cities that do not feature in the first list.

I would like to use these lists to calculate the ratios of travel book shops in the 6 highest count cities.

The common key will be 'city' as this appears in documents of both lists
i.e. in list 2 : city1: 42 divided by in list 1: city1: 84 = 0.5 ratio

I am unsure of how to do this in pymongo as the information is in mongo documents within a list.

I thought some kind of nested loop would work:

```
 dict={} 
 for i in sixcities: #loop through the first list
   dict[i["_id"]]=i["count"]  
   for i in travelcities: #loop through second list
     dict[i["_id"]]=i["count"]/(dict[i["_id"]]) #ratio
```

But I am getting the following result:
    KeyError: 'city15'
This city does not appear in the first list as one of the 6 with the most bookshops, but it does appear in the second as containing a travel bookshop.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems in your code is that you are using same variable 'i' in both outer and inner loop

Consider this code which, for each city in first list search for it in the second list, then computes the ratio.

```
dict={} 
for i in sixcities: #loop through the first list
    dict[i["_id"]]=i["count"]  
    for j in travelcities: #loop through second list
        if j["_id"] == i["_id"]:
            dict[i["_id"]]=j["count"]/(dict[i["_id"]]) #ratio
```

Do note that if the city does not exist in the second list the answer remains the count of the city in the first list. Handle this corner case in the way you want.

Comment: Yes and also not using if condition inside second for loop, to perform ratio only when cities match.